# Scala List.contains(x) return false, but exists(_.== x) returns true

Tags: list, scala, collections, contains, exists

I'm working with some simple data structures and collections in Scala and I've noticed what I think is strange behavior. Here's the object:

```
class State (protected val trackmap: Map[Int, List[String]]) {

  override def clone : State = {
    new State(Map() ++ trackmap)
  }

  override def toString = { "State: " + trackmap.toString }

  def equals (other: State) : Boolean = {
    //println("Comparing " + trackmap + " to " + other.trackmap)
    trackmap == other.trackmap  

  }

  def == (other: State) : Boolean = {
    this equals other
  }
}
```

And my related tests:

```
  test("state equality") {
    val state = new State( Map(1 -> List("engine"), 2 -> List("a"), 3 -> List("b")) )

    expect(true) { state equals state.clone }
    expect(true) { state == state.clone }
    expect(false) { state == new State(Map(1 -> List("a"))) }
    expect(false) { state equals new State(Map(1 -> List("a"))) }

    expect(true) { List(state).exists( _.equals (state.clone) )}
    expect(true) { List(state).exists( _.== (state.clone) )}
    expect(true) { List(state).contains( state.clone )}
  }
```

All of them pass except for the last one, which I expect should pass. I haven't looked at the Scala source, but I assume contains would be implemented basically as the second exists call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not overriding the *actual* equals method of Scala, that is why it behaves strangely.
Re-write your equals method as this, and things should work:

```
override def equals (other: Any) : Boolean = {
    other match{
      case that: State =>
        //println("Comparing " + trackmap + " to " + other.trackmap)
        trackmap == that.trackmap
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

See, equals method in Scala takes a parameter of type Any not State, and you need to add the `override` keyword for it.

BTW, you don't even need the == method, as Scala automatically remaps it to equals method!

Comment: Note that this can also be evidenced by the fact that while `List(state).exists( _ == state.clone )` returns `true`,  `List(state).exists( _ == (state.clone:Any) )` returns `false`.

Comment: using pattern matching in your `equals` implementation would be much more idiomatic than the `isInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf` combo.

Comment: Yeah true. I will fix it now. thanks for the suggestion (I am still a bit Javaish about Scala)

Answer (score 4):

Your `equals` method isn't being called by `contains`, because you didn't override the default implementation on `Any`. The clue to this is that the compiler doesn't complain about the lack of an `override` modifier.

The correct method signature would be

```
override def equals(other: Any): Boolean
```

When you called `List(state).exists( _.equals (state.clone)`, it resolved to your implementation, because the compiler knew the type of the argument was `State`. Thus it chose the overloaded variant of the method which was specialized to that type.

The signature of `contains` *always* takes an argument of type `Any`, regardless of the type parameter of the `List`, so the method call will resolve to the default implementation of `equals`.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `equals` and `==` is not as it should be. For that reason Scala has the `case` class.

Your class would then look like this

```
case class State(protected val trackmap: Map[Int, List[String]]) {

  override def clone: State = {
    new State(Map() ++ trackmap)
  }

  override def toString = { "State: " + trackmap.toString }
}
```

If you wanted to implement them manually you would need to implement the `Equals` trait. And override the following methods:

```
override def canEqual(other: Any) = 
  other.isInstanceOf[State]

override def equals(other: Any) = {
  other match {
    case that: State => (that canEqual this) && trackmap == that.trackmap
    case _ => false
  }
}

override def hashCode() = {
  val prime = 41
  prime + trackmap.hashCode
}
```